# about oriented design & procedure oriented design

Tags: function, oop, design-patterns

I have very basic question on object oriented design. What is better object oriented design or procedure oriented design?

Consider an example.

I design a util to send mail based on some parameters. If i design procedure oriented way i will do like this.

```
MailUtil.sendMail(String username, String passwork, String subject, String message, String toList, String bccList, ...)
```

If i design this as object oriented way i will go like below

MailUtil.sendMail(IMailContentProducer)

```
definition of IMailContentProducer
interface IMailContentProducer {
     String getUserName(),
     String getPassword(), 
     String getSubject(),
     String getSubject(),
     String getToList(), 
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a question of "best way to",

It's much more about the way you want your code to be done than the right way to do it :

POD : A fast developped, unflexible system, hardly reusable without tweaking.

OOP : A slower developped, more flexible & easily reusable system.

Comment: is it really "slow to develop" when we go for OOPS? both take same time :(

Comment: The time you're waisting on oop (design, think of reusability, dependancy limitation etc) you gain it on next project + code maintainibility so... overall you'll gain time